# MySQL - SELECT equal amount of each in UNION by total LIMIT

Tags: mysql, union, sql-limit

In a MySQL database I have 3 tables: `customers`, `projects` and `tasks`. For a search that I am implementing, I want to search through all 3 tables and select found matches. The problem is that I would like to equally limit the amount of results returned by MySQL.

This is an example with the query that I currently have:

```
SELECT id, title, type
FROM (
    (
    SELECT id, title, 'customer' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM customers
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
    SELECT id, title, 'project' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM projects
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
    SELECT id, title, 'task' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM tasks
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
) res
LIMIT 6;
```

In this example, I want to limit the results to 6.

My desired endresult for this example is the following:

1) If all tables have at least 2 results, show 2 results for each.

```
id     title                      type
20     'First test customer'      'customer'
22     'Test customer 2'          'customer
48     'A project for testing'    'project'
17     'Test Project'             'project'
1      'Task test'                'task'
2      'Second test'              'task'
```

2) If one table does not have any results, show 3 results for each of the 2 other tables. (If only one table has results, show 6 results for that table.)

```
id     title                      type
20     'First test customer'      'customer'
22     'Test customer 2'          'customer
56     'Customer test 56'         'customer'
1      'Task test'                'task'
2      'Second test'              'task'
3      'Test task'                'task'
```

3) If 2 of the tables have more than 2 results, and the third table only has 1 result, show 3 results for one of the tables with enough results, 2 results for the other one of the two and 1 for the table with only 1 result.

```
id     title                      type
20     'First test customer'      'customer'
48     'A project for testing'    'project'
17     'Test Project'             'project'
34     'Testing project'          'project'
1      'Task test'                'task'
2      'Second test'              'task'
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a row number for every single `SELECT` and then order the `UNION` with that calculated field to balance the results obtained from the single queries (I've not tested this code, please take it as a starting point):

```
SET @rank1=0;
SET @rank2=0;
SET @rank3=0;
SELECT id, title, type, rank
FROM (
    (

    SELECT @rank1:=@rank1+1 AS rank, id, title, 'customer' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM customers
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (

    SELECT @rank2:=@rank2+1 AS rank, id, title, 'project' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM projects
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (

    SELECT @rank3:=@rank3+1 AS rank, id, title, 'task' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM tasks
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
) res
ORDER BY rank 
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but MySQL doesn't seem to let me use the `SET` (Syntax error). Any chance you know why?

Comment: @DylanVB I've edited the answer: probably the set declaration statement should be outside the select

Comment: Declaring the variables outside of the query indeed works. Would there be any way to set the variables inside the query?

Comment: @DylanVB yes I answered it in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

To have the @kiks73 result in one query without declaring @rankX variables you can add a `(SELECT @rankX:=0) AS t` to the from clause. like this:

```
SELECT id, title, type, rank
FROM (
    (

    SELECT @rank1:=@rank1+1 AS rank, id, title, 'customer' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM customers,(SELECT @rank1:=0) AS t
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (

    SELECT @rank2:=@rank2+1 AS rank, id, title, 'project' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM projects,(SELECT @rank2:=0) AS t
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (

    SELECT @rank3:=@rank3+1 AS rank, id, title, 'task' AS type, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM tasks,(SELECT @rank3:=0) AS t
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+test* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
) res
ORDER BY rank
LIMIT 6;
```